# Liclipse splitting editor window

Tags: editor, pydev, liclipse

How can we split editor window in Liclipse editor so that it shows two different file at the same time in two different tab ? Similar to vi-editor's -O options which is used like this

```
vi -O file1.txt file2.txt
```

Currently I see that the "Vertical split" option in "Window > Editor" opens a new tab but with same file.

[image: Screenshot of editor window split]

Answer (score 0):

Got this response from an email which works!

> The vertical split option really only works for seeing the same file side-by-side. To see 2 different files side by side you have to drag
>   the editor tab title, positioning as you would position any other view
>   (so, you can have it undocked or docked as you want).
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Fabio